# Python.exe keeps running after closing Gtk.main() when both Gtk and win32ui modules are imported

Tags: windows, python-2.7, gtk3, pywin32, pygobject

I run python 2.7.13 on windows 7.
I am creating a window with Gtk (from pygobject 3.18.2).
I also use win32ui (from pywin32 221).
When I import both modules my program runs just fine untill I close it. The window is closing fine, but the python process keeps running and the cmd window that is used to run the script does not return to de cmd prompt.
I have to kill python to get back to the prompt
Here is a simple test script. This does not close proper on my system. If I comment out

```
#import win32ui
```

it will close proper

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import win32ui

class Window(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

Window()
Gtk.main()
```

Looks like a conflict between Gtk and win32ui.
I need win32gui and win32ui for extracting icons from pe files.
What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On previous versions of PyWin32: 
https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/609/
https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/636/

```
import atexit, os

def taskkill_this():
    # kill this process
    current_pid = os.getpid()
    os.system("taskkill /pid %s /f" % current_pid)

atexit.register(taskkill_this)
```

Appears to be one provided workaround.

Upon further inspection, it appears to be related to pywin32 and Gtk UI event processes clashing. I would recommend using one or the other rather than both if possible or use a taskkill hack like the one above.

I've also noticed that this has happened on Windows 7 workstations in all cases I have seen.

Comment: Thank you it does solve my problem for now. Still hoping for a more elegant solution though.

Comment: I'll test running it on other versions of Python and Windows when I can and update my answer if I find anything else.

Comment: I also use win32api, win32con and win32gui from pywin32. Only win32ui seems to cause problems